# How to fetch selected fields in graphql backend using type-graphql resolver function?

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, typegraphql

I am writing a resolver to fetch data from REST api to graphql backend function using typescript and type-graphql.The issue I am facing is I am getting data from API with all props but I want to return only selected fields in front end. How to return only selected fields?

> Here is my scenario. I have react app as front end. I will write all
> graphql queries in fronetend app. There is apollo client in front end which
> connects to graphql in backend. Backend is node app written in
> typescript. My backend fetches data
> from rest api and serves to front end via apollo server. We use type-graphql in backend

***Here in this question I have doubts for backend.***

I have following type *(defined in backend as personInfo.ts)*

```
import { ObjectType, Field } from "type-graphql";

@ObjectType("PersonInfo")
export class PersonInfo {
  @Field({ nullable: true }) firstName: string;
  @Field({ nullable: true }) lastName: string;
  @Field({ nullable: true }) registrationNo: string;
  @Field({ nullable: true }) personCode: string;
  @Field({ nullable: true }) personCapabilities: string;
}
```

I am using above type in my resolver like below: *(defined in backend as personInfoResolver.ts) This graphql resolver will fetch data from rest api using function written in next part. This function has issue as stated in code below.*

```
import { Query, Resolver, Arg } from "type-graphql";
import { PersonInfo } from "../types";
import { GetPersonInfo } from "./api/helpers";

@Resolver((of) => PersonInfo)
export class PersonInfoResolver {
  @Query((returns) => PersonInfo, { nullable: true })
  async PersonInfo(@Arg("serialNo") serialNo: string) {
    console.log(await GetPersonInfo(serialNo)); //<--this logs full object received from api with all the fields
    return await GetPersonInfo(serialNo); //when queried from graphql playground, i get null for selected values even if previous line prints all data
  }
}
```

Here is function to get data in api helper *(Defined in backend to connect to api and get data.) WOrks fine and gets all objects from rest api.*

```
export const GetPersonInfo = async (serialNo: string) => {
  var personInfoURL = "url" + serialNo;
  if (!serialNo) {
    return "";
  }
  const response = await posApi
    .get(personInfoURL)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {});

  const data = await response;

  return data;
};
```

I am testing above code using graphql playground using following query.

```
  {
    PersonInfo(serialNo:"201123030"){
     firstName
     lastName
     registrationNo
     registrationNo
     personCapabilities

 }
}
```

Comment: This question is incomplete, where's your graphql-query/mutation?

Comment: Or, is that what you are wondering? How to write graphql-schema-functions?

Comment: @Joel query will be in front end react app. Right now I am writing backend in node and testing using graphql play ground.Added query in question

Comment: I'll upvote it for you, its a good question although pretty messy. Please check my answer below, it shows you what you want.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at my solution?

Comment: Hey, @Joel, Thanks for help. I wrote resolver and then custome mapper to map received data to local entity. DIdnt use any codegen though.

Comment: Glad to hear that! It is optional part of solution, but very useful, i recommend checking it out! :)

Comment: of course, I checked it. Will surely use it when needed. Thanks for pointing it out and helping by detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear to me, but I'll try to help you out.

First of all, that GraphQL schema you provided is invalid.

In the Playground, you should write:

```
{
    PersonInfo(serialNo: "201123030") { //not DetailsInfo
        firstName
        ...
    }

}
```

*Given that your entity looks like this*:

```
@Column()
@Field({ nullable: true }) firstName: string;
@Column()
@Field({ nullable: true }) lastName: string;
@Column()
@Field({ nullable: true }) registrationNo: string;
@Column()
@Field({ nullable: true }) personCode: string;
@Column()
@Field({ nullable: true }) personCapabilities: string;
```

*And that your resolver looks like this*:

```
@Resolver(PersonInfo)
export class PersonInfoResolver {
  @Query(() => PersonInfo, { nullable: true })
  async PersonInfo(@Arg("serialNo") serialNo: string): Promise<PersonInfo> {
    return await GetPersonInfo(serialNo); //when queried from graphql playground, i get null for selected values even if previous line prints all data
  }
}
```

I recommend running

```
npm i -D @graphql-codegen @graphql-codegen/cli @graphql-codegen/typescript @graphql-codegen/operations @graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo
```

which allows for automatic schema-generations and typesafety in your project.

Create a file called `codegen.yml` in your root-directory of your react-project (same location as `package.json`)

```
overwrite: true
schema: "http://localhost:4000/graphql"
documents: "src/graphql/**/*.graphql"
generates:
  src/generated/graphql.tsx:
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
      - "typescript-operations"
```

Create the folder `generated` in `src/*`.

OR, change the structure above to whereever you want the schemas to be generated.

You first need to create `personinfo.query.graphql` in `src/graphql/queries/*`

(You could also create another folder called `src/graphql/mutations/` here)

`personinfo.query.graphql`

```
query PersonInfo($serialNo: String!) { 
     personInfo(serialNo: $serialNo) {
         firstName,
         lastName,
         registrationNo,
         personCode,
         personCapabilities  //or whatever subset of fields you want.
     }
}
```

In your console type: `graphql-codegen --config codegen.yml` and the files will be generated. Open `graphql.tsx` now and see what it has created. Pretty neat right?

Then in your react-component just do:

```
export const MyComponent: React.FC<{}> = ({}) => {

    const [{data}] = usePersonInfoQuery({/*your serialNo here*/}); //this function will have been generated now
    //then you have access to the fields you supplied to `personinfo.query.graphql`
    const fName = data.personInfo.firstName;
    const lName = data.personInfo.lastName;

}
```

Comment: detailsinfo is just copy paste error. It was earlier detailsinfo. Updated in question. Also added more context info.

Comment: @GauravChauhan Please check my solution, it shows you how to select a subset of fields in your frontend with apollo.